# Cordova notification exit app

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, cordova

I've app in which clicking back button prompts notification window to confirm app exit. Button 'Yes' and 'No' works perfectly, but when I click outside notification window it exits the app.

Code:

```
![document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); //Listen to the User clicking on the back button
}

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit ?", onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Yes,No"); 
    // Prompt the user with the choice
}

function onConfirm(button) {
    if(button==2){//If User selected No, then we just do nothing
        return;
    }else{
        navigator.app.exitApp();// Otherwise we quit the app.
    }
}][1]
```

What can be the error?

Also is there any solution to close app on multiple back button clicks?

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

change the `onConfirm` to

```
function onConfirm(button) {
    if(button==1){
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}
```

To close on multiple back buttons, use a counter that increments on back pressed, and reset it on confirm, when you press the back button and the counter is 1 or greater, call `navigator.app.exitApp();`